# Rust - How to use unsized trait objects in structs

Tags: memory-management, struct, rust, compiler-errors, traits

Trying to learn Rust by writing a parser, but this error is killing me:

```
ast.rs(7, 11): this trait cannot be made into an object...
ast.rs(7, 29): ...because it requires `Self: Sized`
ast.rs(16, 5): the trait `ast::ast::Statement` cannot be made into an object
```

Here's the code:

```
use crate::token::token;

pub trait Node {
    fn token_literal(&mut self) -> String;
}

pub trait Statement: Node + Clone {
    fn statement_node(&mut self);
}

pub trait Expression: Node + Clone {
    fn expression_node(&mut self);
}

pub struct Program {
    pub statements: Vec<Box<dyn Statement>>,
}
```

And I'd like to know why does it keep complaining me about the Sized trait, I'm using Box to avoid it and lifetimes?

I do not want to use Generics for the `Program` struct like

```
pub struct Program<T: Statement> {
    pub statements: Vec<T>
}
```

because when I return a `Program` from a function it complains me about some kind of an error like 
"it requires 1 argument but got 0"

Comment: @E_net4isdownhausted So you're saying that the `Box` gets invalid because of the clone trait? But why? I suppose that when we clone a Box, we clone the pointer itself which doesn't even satisfy my needs but enough to make compiler not complain. Isn't Box a type of a pointer?

Comment: _"I suppose that when we clone a Box, we clone the pointer itself"_ That is incorrect, a `Box` provides unique ownership over the pointed value, so even cloning requires the owned value to be cloneable. To attain shared ownership, one would instead use reference-counted smart pointers: `Rc` or `Arc`.

Comment: @E_net4isdownhausted But using `Vec<Arc<dyn Statement>>`, instead of `Vec<Box<dyn Statement>>` didn't solve the issue either. And I understood that if I use the reference-counted pointers to clone an unsized object, it'll clone the reference, not the value am I right?

Comment: That is true. Please try the solution in the duplicate target.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that `Clone` requires `Sized`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/clone.rs.html#108-110.